# How to rewrite the text of buttons that are not separately defined

Tags: java, swing

I have started trying to write a code similar to the game 2048, however the size of the board can have any value depending on what the user inputs. I decided to make the numbers on the board, for style purposes, separate buttons.

This is the current GUI:

[image]

How can I make it so that when the buttons: up, down left, or right are pressed each of the button's in the board texts are changed? I know about event listeners I just mean how can I replace the button's in the same grid with different values when I defined the buttons on the board as:

```
`for(int i = 2; i < rows + 2; i++) {
  for(int j = 2; j < columns + 2; j++) {
    gbc.gridx = j;
    gbc.gridy = i;
    num = new JButton(board.board[j-2][i-2].getValue()+"");
    num.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, screenSize.height/50));
    num.setEnabled(false);
    this.add(num, gbc);
  }
}`
```

The only ideas I've had was to create an array of buttons and then change the button's text in the array of buttons and then replace the old array of buttons with the new one. Also sorry if it has some super simple answer that I just couldn't find, I am just about finished with one semester of coding courses in college.

Comment: `The only ideas I've had was to create an array of buttons and then change the button's text in the array of buttons` - sounds reasonable. `then replace the old array of buttons with the new one` - there is not need to replace the buttons. The Array just holds a reference to the button. So if you change the text of the button, the text will but updated on the button in the GUI since its the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the `JButtons` on a `HashMap` and use column number and row number as a key to find the correct button.

Something like:

```
Map<String, JButton> grid = new HashMap<String, JButton>;

for(int i = 2; i < rows + 2; i++) {
    for(int j = 2; j < columns + 2; j++) {
        grid.put(String.valueOf(i) + String.valueOf(i), new JButton("some text"));
        // we transform the integers into String, otherwise the operator "+" will sum them
        // instead of concatenate them.
     }
}
```

Now you cant get the desired button with `grid.get(row + column)`;

```
JButton bt;
JButton bt = grid.get("4" + "6");
bt.setText("different text");
grid.put("4" + "6", bt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use Buttons to do such a game button it's something that you can click on it since your are not supposed to click on numbers. If I were you I would use a gamePanel which contains fixed labels since it's easier changing text of label than moving label.
I would add MouseListener to the gamePanel and then fill implemented methods in order to manage when the mouse left button is pressed and move to left and so on.
So create an array of Label.
Create a method which add and move numbers according to the direction of the move. For instance if you make a left to right move you will start to add the numbers of the first column into the second column when they have same values. Next you just have to do it recursively until the last column. 
If you need a bit more explainations ,I'll be pleased to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Personally I was trying to use buttons because of how they looked so I'm looking for a way to get that to work, would it be possible to set the text of the buttons according to the array of labels? Also as for the functionality I have that all working

Comment: Ok so you could do a 1dimension JButton Array. Like JButton [] buttons; 
To  get a button with position : button[i*rows+y]
To change text you don't have to recreate a new Array you just need to do:  button[i * rows+y].setText(newValue);